# SVN and LAMP Server together cannot access

Tags: svn

I have a LAMP server where locally a database is created and all the databases are stored in `/var/www/html/companyadmin` and we can access the server by typing in browser the ip address of server ie `192.168.2.2`

Then I installed svn in this server and put svn directory in `/usr/etc/svn` and created a repository named `companyrepo`. I have modified the `subversion.conf` file and set `SVNParentpath` to `/usr/etc/svn`.

When I tried to access my svn repository from browser ie `http://192.168.2.2/svn/companyrepo`, then the default homepage for the serer appears. I have tested in another machine where no web server is installed and I can access svn repository from browser. But the machine where LAMP is installed only the default page appears.

What should I do to make the server works in proper way.

Comment: Is there anything in Apache's error.log? Try /var/log/httpd/error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log depending on your distro. Does the subversion config definitely take precedent over your main site's configuration? (And why /usr/etc?)

Comment: Have you checked that the `mod_dav_svn` Apache module is installed?

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that your LAMP package doesn't have `mod_dav_svn` installed. XAMPP doesn't come with this module. You have two choices:

- You can try [these directions](http://www.doitscared.com/97/add-subversion-to-the-xampp-apache-server/).
- You can just run the Subversion server with `svnserve` rather than through Apache. The `svnserve` is actually faster and lighter weight than running Subversion under Apache. The big reason for using Apache over `svnserve` has to do with open ports: Your firewall will probably allow `http` on Port 80 through, but not `svn` on Port 3690. The other is that it's easier to get LDAP (and Windows Active Directory) logins though Apache rather than through `svnserve. Also,`svnserve`isn't normally encrypted while Apache`https`is encrypted. If none of these are issues, then the easiest is to use`svnserve` rather than Apache.

Comment: I'd guess he does have the module: he said he 'modified the subversion.conf', which I'd expect to be packaged with it.

Comment: That could be the case. I have no idea what LAMP he got. Normally, the standard RPM Linux repositories include Apache, SVN integration, PHP integration, etc. You don't usually need an actual LAMP package. I've seen LAMP employed in RHEL and SUSE where _packages_ tend to be older versions (like Perl 5.10). I worked on SUSE a few years ago, and SVN was version 1.3 when 1.6 was already out.

Comment: Dear David..My OS is Centos 6.5,I have separately installed apache,mysql and php from yum repository and everything is correctly installed and working.I disabled the firewall.mod_dav_svn is installed. If I install svn in other centos machine its working fine,but problem is the machine where i installed mysql,php,apache..when issue svn command in browser the webpage is opening instead of svn repo.Shall i have to add something to php.ini file,so that when i type /svn it directs to svn directory instead of /var/www/html/comapnyadmin...thanks for your comments..

Comment: Are you able to checkout from Subversion using the `svn` command? Is the issue just attempting to do the browsing? When you setup `Location` directives in httpd, it's possible that one is overriding another which is why you get the server webpage rather than Subversion. If you want to browse the Subversion repo, you can look at setting up [Sventon](http://sventon.org). Without seeing your httpd setup, it's hard to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks David....i am checking now whether i am able to import,checkout datas through terminal or not. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I modified subversion.conf file and in around line number 28, the command associated with `<location>`is different.And after changing it to svn i.e (`<location/svn>`), it works perfectly.